# Generar CreateView con dos modelos, en un modelo one-to-many

Tags: python, django

Tengo una base de datos [image: Base de datos]

y deseo generar una CreateView para ingresar "RegistroEntradas" con sus respectivas relaciones, es decir que le pueda agregar el form de el detalle_registroEntrada.

Clase MateriaPrima(representa producto en la imagen)

```
class MateriaPrima(models.Model):
nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
stock = models.IntegerField(default=0)
rendimiento = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5,decimal_places=2,default=0)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Meta:
     verbose_name = "Stock"
     verbose_name_plural = "Stocks"

def __str__(self):
    return self.nombre
```

Ahora las clases RegistroEntrada

```
class RegistroEntrada(models.Model):
id_usuario = models.ForeignKey(User,verbose_name="Empleado",on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                                        related_name='registroentradas')
fecha = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

y Detalle_RegistroEntrada

```
class Detalle_RegistroEntrada(models.Model):
id_RemitoEntrada = models.ForeignKey(RegistroEntrada,on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                   related_name='detalle_registroentradas')
cantidad = models.IntegerField()
id_producto = models.ForeignKey(MateriaPrima,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default='')
```

Comment: y cual es el problema, que te falla agrega lo que quieres hacer en tu CreateView y lo que tienes

Comment: basicamente no se como agregar dos formularios a una createview, estuve viendo que existe la funcion inlineformset_factory pero sigo sin poder resolver el problema